# C++ compilation error class inheritance

Tags: c++

could someone explain the reason why the following simple codes does not compile? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
    Base () {}      
    virtual void f() {cout << 1;}
    virtual void f(int i) {cout << i;}
};

class Derived: public Base  {
public:
    Derived() {}
    void f() {cout << 3;}
};

int main() {

    Derived d;
    d.f(7); // Compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>  prog.cpp:19:8: error: no
>   matching function for call to 'Derived::f(int)'   d.f(7); //Compilation Error
>          ^
>  
>   prog.cpp:13:7: note: candidate: void Derived::f()
>    void f() {cout << 3;}
>          ^
>  prog.cpp:13:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

Comment: Try adding `using Base::f(int)` in your `Derived` class.

Comment: Your `Derived` class inherits from your `Base` class, which has two versions of function `f`, if you only override the `f` function without a parameter, the compiler thinks that that is the only `f` function call that is available in the `Derived` class. Therefore, you must override both `f` function calls or remove the all overrides

Comment: Also you don't need those empty constructors

Comment: @PreferenceBean Right, sorry

Comment: /OT @PreferenceBean Tomalak changed their name again? ;-) ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer!